# ЯндексКарты api событие fire вместо events.add не работает

Tags: яндекс-карты

```js
  myMap.events.add('click', function (e)
{
if (needed_point)
obj_collection.removeFromMap(myMap);
//смотрим на координаты щелчка
//var coords = e.get('coordPosition');
needed_point = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {},{preset: 'twirl#blueStretchyIcon', draggable: false});
obj_collection = ymaps.geoQuery(needed_point).addToMap(myMap);
console.log(coords);
//находим ближайшую точку мкада
var closestObject = arPlacemarksRez.getClosestTo(coords);
//составляем маршрут между двумя точками
ymaps.route([
closestObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
coords
]).then(function (route) {
//myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
//пишем дистанцию на метке
var distance = Math.round(route.getLength()/1000);
needed_point.properties.set({iconContent: distance});
});
});
```

меняю на

```js
myMap.events.fire('click', function (e)
{
if (needed_point)
obj_collection.removeFromMap(myMap);

//смотрим на координаты щелчка
//var coords = e.get('coordPosition');
needed_point = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {},{preset: 'twirl#blueStretchyIcon', draggable: false});
obj_collection = ymaps.geoQuery(needed_point).addToMap(myMap);
console.log(coords);

//находим ближайшую точку мкада
var closestObject = arPlacemarksRez.getClosestTo(coords);

//составляем маршрут между двумя точками
ymaps.route([
closestObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
coords
]).then(function (route) {
//myMap.geoObjects.add(route);

//пишем дистанцию на метке
var distance = Math.round(route.getLength()/1000);
needed_point.properties.set({iconContent: distance});
});


});
```

ничего не происходит

Comment: А зачем меняете? В чем цель? Это ведь разные методы

Comment: Метка появляется после клика, а надо при загрузке страницы

Comment: Значит обработчик события нужно вызвать после загрузки страницы или после создания карты. Метод fire нужен для вызова обработчиков которые ранее были указаны при помощи add

Comment: код ниже все равно не работает. Как избавится от обязательного клика?

Comment: Соберите пример вашего кода на jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3a91okw5/ Сейчас у вас какой-то кусок кода вырванный из контекста. Если вы не собираетесь обрабатывать клик пользователя по карте, то не надо создавать myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {})

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dr7bmvj2/1/ вот здесь

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3gc1jda2/ Запрос к геокодеру выполняется не моментально. Соответственно если в хотите использовать какие-то данные, которые получили от геокодера, то нужно дождаться выполнения запроса от геокодера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос к геокодеру выполняется не моментально. Соответственно если в хотите использовать какие-то данные, которые получили от геокодера, то нужно дождаться выполнения запроса от геокодера.

```
var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode("Жуквоский");
myGeocoder.then(
    function (res) {
        var coords = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
        // здесь добавляем маршрут
        addRoute(coords);
    },
    function (err) {
        alert('Ошибка. Адрес не определен'); 
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3gc1jda2

Comment: Подскажите условие, не строить маршрут если метка внутри Мкад, просто отображать пустую метку

Comment: Попадание точки можно проверить как в этом примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemarks_in_circle